# SVD image reconstruction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, svd

I am trying to do a Singular Value Decomposition of this image:

[image]

taking the first 10 values. I have this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('bee.jpg')
img = np.mean(img, 2)
U,s,V = np.linalg.svd(img)
recon_img = U @ s[1:10] @ V
```

but when I run it it throws me this error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 9 is different from 819)
```

So I think I do something wrong when I do the reconstruction. I am not sure of the dimensions of the matrix `np.linalg.svd(img)` creates.
How can I solve?

Sorry for the english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the dimension of `s`, if you print the `U`, `s` and `V` dimensions, I get:

```
print(np.shape(U))
print(np.shape(s))
print(np.shape(V))

(819, 819)
(819,)
(1024, 1024)
```

So `U` and `V` are square matrix, `s` is an array. You have to create a matrix with the same dimensions of you image (819 x 1024) with `s` on the main diagonal with this:

```
n = 10
S = np.zeros(np.shape(img))
for i in range(0, n):
    S[i,i] = s[i]
print(np.shape(S))
```

output:

```
(819, 1024)
```

Then you can proceed with your elaboration. For a comparison, check this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('bee.jpg')
img = np.mean(img, 2)

U,s,V = np.linalg.svd(img)

n = 10
S = np.zeros(np.shape(img))
for i in range(0, n):
    S[i,i] = s[i]

recon_img = U @ S @ V

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].set_title('Original')

ax[1].imshow(recon_img)
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].set_title(f'Reconstructed n = {n}')

plt.show()
```

which give me this:

[image]

Comment: You can also use np.diag(s) to span the diagonal, which is probably faster and easier to read